# how to create adjustable gap between elements (div)

Tags: css-position

im trying to create an even and adjustable gap between divs but i can find an elegant way to do so. thanks for your help.

[how i dont want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RJvG.jpg)

[and how i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gHVd.jpg)

this is the only way i found in order to create the gap but im sure there is a better way.

```css
#big {
    height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
 border: 1px solid #FF0000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin:auto;
 position:relative;
 top:;
 right:
 left:
}
.small {
 height: 50px;
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #FF0000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #308014;
    margin:4px;
 position:relative;
 top:150px;
 left:200px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <title>Result</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <div id="big">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either u can give margin-bottom or padding-bottom but for last div margin bottom is not necessary.

so you can try

```
.small{
margin: 0 0 4px 0
}
.small:last-of-type{
   margin-bottom:0;
}
```